# Symfony Doctrine Filter and 404

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with the following scenario:

I have a list of products and every product has a flag to be public or not, meaning can be viewable by logged only users or both logged and anonymous.

In order to achieve the filtering in doctrine level I created a filter which checks if user is logged and if not filters only the products that are public.

My problem now is that if someone not logged tries to view a non public product Symfony throws 404. Of course it does the right thing but in my side I would like to return 403 if product really exists but is non public.

So my question is:

1) Remove filter and change whole implementation using voters?

or

2) Add an an exception listener on kernel request and there check if product really exists and transform response from 404 to 403? (well redundant db queries then :( )

or

3) Something else?

This need to be done on every single action, I need to do it in a level where actions won't get involved (otherwise it will use same logic to many places in the code and also there is big possibility to forget to do this check in a single check and break security).

Comment: *I created a filter* Can you please explain what is that filter?

Comment: Please don't ask about *best practice*, that's not a valid question on Stack Overflow, see why [*primarly opinion-based* question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) are closed in the Help section.

Comment: I mean Doctrine Filter when i say filter

Comment: Why not use a generic Repository function for it?

Comment: Perhaps show us the code you are using.  You could use a custom ParamConverter with a service that grabs the user/roles, and return queries/throw exceptions based on that.